# D3.js (Wilkinson type) Dot Plot Example

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, plot

I've searched, but been unable to find an example of a dot plot in D3. Is anyone aware of this type of plot having been implemented in any of the charting libraries built on D3, or an example in base D3?

Just to be clear, a dot plot is similar to a histogram except that points are stacked on top of one another in place of a histogram's bars. In R this can be created using the ggplot package.

```
qplot(x=rnorm(200),geom="dotplot")
```

[image]

Edit:

So as Lars pointed out, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186636/dot-plot-in-d3-js) solves the problem when the data has been aggregated into an array with the number of points in a column. In my case, I want to display interactive information about each of the points (e.g. a tool tip with the actual underlying data value), so I can't aggregate in this way. Here is some example data that I'd like to plot.

```
data = [0.4897,0.7685,-0.7367,-0.7483,-0.5149,0.0448,-1.7294,1.8667,1.0116,0.3896,-0.4267,-0.1161,-1.4618,-1.3198,-1.999,1.2883,1.7123,-1.5902,-0.7937,1.0359,-0.485,-0.2391,0.4136,-0.2506,0.7333,1.1902,0.7132,-0.3096,0.4793,-0.7779,-0.19,-0.0855,1.4498,1.0196,0.537,0.5341,0.5363,0.2664,-0.8586,-0.5667,1.2263,1.508,-0.139,-0.3015,-0.3679,0.483,0.9381,-0.1298,-0.1024,1.3079,-0.9554,1.167,0.3245,1.0424,-0.3589,1.3943,2.2537,-1.3225,0.8814,-0.2723,0.3782,0.8982,0.4167,0.1614,0.5659,-0.4672,-0.7634,-0.8591,-1.0887,0.4374,0.3618,-0.7074,-0.9812,-0.6216,1.0774,0.9979,-0.799,1.186,0.5704,1.8626,1.4321,0.3179,1.6356,0.1646,2.1265,-0.2409,0.0043,1.1503,-1.615,-0.677,-0.5573,1.9954,0.8123,-0.8011,0.2088,0.5007,0.9113,-0.8742,-0.5857,0.409,-1.0702,-0.016,0.6822,1.0133,-1.2022,0.0561,0.8704,-1.5982,1.6676,-0.0344,-1.739,-2.0362,-1.1955,0.7838,0.5037,-0.2123,0.2951,1.0192,0.97,0.2384,-0.2223,-0.1448,0.9924,1.5586,1.4238,-2.4781,-0.2456,-1.8822,-0.4424,-0.5941,-0.9948,1.8733,-0.2242,-1.5359,-0.103,0.7378,0.7691,0.069,0.3952,-0.4267,-0.2077,-0.4327,-1.1705,0.0399,-0.6586,0.1043,2.9475,-0.4968,-0.5432,0.4924,1.2173,0.177,0.2861,-0.709,1.4922,-1.1633,-0.084,-1.2275,0.5193,0.2404,-1.4495,-0.3346,0.3153,-0.573,0.4139,-0.9114,1.4844,0.1166,0.8734,2.182,-0.3765,2.0888,1.1178,0.2684,-0.5803,0.893,0.2127,-0.107,0.0569,1.0699,0.2975,1.3017,0.4541,1.8337,0.7915,1.705,-0.2708,-0.9626,1.1994,-1.6666,1.2642,0.5244,-1.1757,0.9278,0.882,-0.8993,1.2435,0.3841,0.6815,-0.1459]
```

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186636/dot-plot-in-d3-js)?

Comment: I don't Follow @LarsKotthoff. I'd like to create a d3.js plot like the above R plot. It is a fairly standard plot, so I imagined that there would already be an implementation flowing around the interwebs.

Comment: ahh, sorry. You are right. I'd like a similar plot, but using disaggregated data so that I can add interactive elements allowing the user to get info about each particular data point.

Comment: That works exactly the same way, except that you don't need to use `d3.range()` to get the data for each point. All you need to do is some preprocessing to sort your data into bins, which you then to the nested selection with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`d3.histogram`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histogram) function to bin your data and then use a nested structure to draw your circles.

See [this bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/gcalmettes/95e3553da26ec90fd0a2890a678f3f69) for the code and a live demo of a self updating dot plot, with interactive information displayed (tooltip) when you `.mouseover` a dot.

Answer (score 0):

The dot plot has nothing to do with a histogram or binning. The method involving d3.histogram would not produce a dot plot. Plase read the reprint of my article at https://www.cs.uic.edu/~wilkinson/Publications/dotplots.pdf. The proper algorithm is given there.