# create a dot chart with d3.js showing stacked dots

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'd like to create a dot chart in d3.js, where it looks kind of like a bar chart, but there are stacked dots instead of bars.

This question is similar to what I want: [D3.js (Wilkinson type) Dot Plot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943938/d3-js-wilkinson-type-dot-plot-example)

I've used that code to try and accomplish what I want, but I'm stuck.

Here is an image showing what I want, based on the data for apples in my CSV file:
[image: dot chart mockup]

The code I have so far is below. When I console.log d3.range(d.apples), I see that I have an array for each day, which is what I want. However I can't figure out how to draw a circle for each spot in the array, where the x axis value would be the day # and the y axis value would be the position in the array + 1.

Any help very welcome! Thank you.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #999;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .dot {
      stroke: none;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 360 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "chart");


    d3.csv("fruit.csv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
        // console.log("data: ", data);

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.day = +d.day;
        d.apples = +d.apples;
      });

      x.domain([0,4]);
      y.domain([0,6]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("class", "label")
          .attr("x", width)
          .attr("y", -6)
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Day");

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("class", "label")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("amount")

      chart.selectAll("g")
          .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dot")
          .attr("r", 3.5)
          .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(d.day); })

                //.attr("cy", function(d,i){ return y(d.apples); })

                .attr("cy", function(d,i,j){ 

                    var range = d3.range(d.apples);
                    console.log("apple range: ", range);

                    return y(range[i])
                })          
          .style("fill", "blue")
          .style("opacity", .5);

    });

    </script>
```

Data (fruit.csv):

```
"day","apples"
1,3
2,6
3,1
4,2
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, because it seems that you have *several*  values for apples in a given day, which is in disagreement with the data you provided. That being said, I posted an answer supposing you're talking about different fruits in each given day: for each day, different dots represent different fruits. If that is **not** what you want, please let me know, so I delete my answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you, but there is just one value for apples for each day. day 1 - 3 apples, day 2 - six apples, day 3 - 1 apple, day 4 - two apples. I want to show a chart that only shows the apple data, and I want it to look like the above image, where a dot is shown for every instance of an apple, not just the total number of apples for a given day. I hope that helps to clarify. I should perhaps, have excluded the pear and orange data as it is unnecessary in this application.

Comment: Yes, now I know what you want. You want a bar chart disguised as a pictogram with circles. Yes, please let only "apples" in the data.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes! Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: I edited my answer with *another* answer, I believe that this is what you want (I also edited the `data` in your question, removing "pears" and "oranges").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want. I believe the most traditional approach is nesting the data and appending several groups, one for each fruit. But, for the sake of simplicity, I'd like to propose a different approach: let's change your data, flattening it, so, in each object, we have only one fruit:

```
originalData.forEach(function(d) {
    data.push({
        day: d.day,
        fruit: "apples",
        amount: +d.apples
    });
    data.push({
        day: d.day,
        fruit: "pears",
        amount: +d.pears
    });
    data.push({
        day: d.day,
        fruit: "oranges",
        amount: +d.oranges
    });
});
```

Where `originalData` is the data array the way it is right now.

Doing that, your data will become something like this:

```
[{
    "day": "1",
    "fruit": "apples",
    "amount": 3
}, {
    "day": "1",
    "fruit": "pears",
    "amount": 6
}, {
    "day": "1",
    "fruit": "oranges",
    "amount": 3
}, {
    "day": "2",
    "fruit": "apples",
    "amount": 6
},//etc...
]
```

Then, we set a ordinal scale for the days:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5);
    .domain(data.map(d => d.day));
```

And, finally, we paint the circles:

```
var dots = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.day);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.amount)
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.fruit)
    })
    .style("opacity", .5);
```

Here is a demo (I put some titles, so you can hover over the dot to check the fruit and the amount):

```js
var rawData = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

    var data = [];

    rawData.forEach(function(d) {
        data.push({
            day: d.day,
            fruit: "apples",
            amount: +d.apples
        });
        data.push({
            day: d.day,
            fruit: "pears",
            amount: +d.pears
        });
        data.push({
            day: d.day,
            fruit: "oranges",
            amount: +d.oranges
        });
    });

    var margin = {
            top: 30,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
        width = 360 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10()
        .domain(["apples", "pears", "oranges"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "chart");

    x.domain(data.map(d => d.day));
    y.domain([0, 10]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", -6)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Day");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("amount");

    var dots = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(d.day);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(d.amount)
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.fruit)
        })
        .style("opacity", .5)
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d){ return d.fruit + ": " + d.amount});
```

```css
pre {
    display: none;
}

body {
    font: 10 px sans - serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #999;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dot {
    stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">"day","apples","pears","oranges"
1,3,6,3
2,6,8,2
3,1,0,7
4,2,3,8</pre>
```

---

**EDIT**: After further clarifications in the comments, this is what OP wants:

Append the groups as you did, but translating them according to the day:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.day) + ".0)";
    });
```

And, in the dots, set the data using `d3.range`:

```
var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d){ return d3.range(+d.apples + 1)})
```

That way, for each group, the data for the circles goes all the way up to the maximum. For example, if in a given day "apples" is 3, the data will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or, if "apples" is 6, the data will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you don't want the leading zero, just do `d3.range(1, +d.apples + 1)`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    },
    width = 360 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var chart = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "chart");

x.domain(data.map(d => d.day));
y.domain([0, 7]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", -6)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Day");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("amount");

var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.day) + ".0)";
    });

var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d) {
        return d3.range(1, +d.apples + 1)
    })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d)
    })
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("opacity", .5);
```

```css
pre {
     display: none;
    }
  
  body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #999;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .dot {
      stroke: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">"day","apples"
1,3
2,6
3,1
4,2</pre>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this so thoroughly-- now I understand what's going on. Cheers.